# Character Encoding Issue PHP & MySQLi

Tags: php, utf-8, character-encoding

I have some info in my database. I subsequently `echo json_encode($array);` the array in which the info is contained and return it to the page displaying the content via AJAX/jQuery.

For example;

**"Dave's apples are sour".**

My webpage displays it as:

**"Daveâ€™s apples are sour".**

This is obviously a character encoding issue. we've never had issues until my hosting company was acquired by a different company.

The header of the page in which the content is displayed contains:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
```

Since then we've tried the following:

- `mysqli_set_charset($conn, "utf8");` <- does not solve the problem
- `echo json_encode( $array, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE );` <- does not solve the problem

A `echo mb_detect_encoding();` on the specific variable that contains "Dave's apples are sour" echoes: "UTF-8".

When examining the console of the page on which the info is displayed reveals that the content arrives to the script "messed up", FireBug shows the response literally being: Daveâ€™s apples are sour.

The column in which the data is contained has the following structure:

ID, Name, Type, Collations

6, BlogPost, text, utf8_general_ci

Does anybody have some new insights? I have been searching for hours on StackOverflow without result.

Comment: Have you verified with a plain MySQL client, entirely out of PHP context that the original text in the database is correctly encoded, and wasn't inserted to a column incapable of handling utf8?

Comment: Here is also a "definitive" guide: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through

Comment: how about `header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8')` ?

Comment: @apokryfos unfortunately no success

Comment: Trace it step by step. Database → PHP, PHP → browser, Javascript  → ??? → display (whatever you're doing there exactly…). Use `echo bin2hex(...)` to see the raw bytes you're dealing with, which helps in narrowing it down at what point the problem occurs. Rule out all the steps in which the string contains the correct bytes.

Comment: Most likely the host is now setting a different default HTTP `Content-Type` header, making the browser interpret the data in a different encoding.

Answer (score -1):

Use to encode:

**json_encode($data,JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE)**

and to decode:

**json_decode($json,false, 512, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);**

Comment: Unfortunately the data is processed by jQuery in the end, not by PHP

Comment: 1) `JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE` would only make the issue *worse*, if anything. 2) `JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE` is not a valid/useful flag for `json_decode`.